# Get all documents from an authenticated user (relation OneToMany)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I am learning to use mongoDB AND ExpressJS by building a Rest API that I would use with ReactJS.

I have always chosen MySQL for the management of my database, but the mongoDB database is not relational and it is still difficult for me to understand.

**An example of what I want to do**

Let's say that I have created a blog and want to get all the articles from a user logged in with an account.

All these operations are managed with a REST API and MongoDB.

How to create a OneToMany relationship between articles and a user.

With MySQL I just had to specify a user_id key for each article in an article table.

But with mongoDB how to create this and especially for a user who is logged in with an account, so that only a logged in user can view his articles.

**EDIT**

I have tried something, it works but I don't know if it's the right approach.

*Context:*

I made a REST API with NodeJS and ExpressJS.

The API will allow a user to organize their applications to facilitate the search for a job.

A user must create an account and log in to take advantage of all of the application's features, so no information is publicly available.

For registration and authentication of a user, I use PassportJS, mongoConnect and ExpressSession

To start, the User model of mongoDB

```
 const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type:String
      },
      email: { 
        type:String, 
        required:true, 
        unique:true
      },
      email_is_verified: {
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
      },
      password: { 
        type:String, 
      },
      referral_code : {
          type:String,
          default: function() {
              let hash = 0;
              for(let i=0; i < this.email.length; i++){
                  hash = this.email.charCodeAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
              }
            let res = (hash & 0x00ffffff).toString(16).toUpperCase();
            return "00000".substring(0, 6 - res.length) + res;         
          }
    },
    referred_by : {
        type: String,
        default:null
    },
    third_party_auth: [ThirdPartyProviderSchema],
        date: {
            type:Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    },
    { strict: false }
  );

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
```

The Apply model represents an apply for a job, for now there is only the title.

To create the OneToMany relationship, I add a User field which refers to my User model

Function to retrieve all applies, so I retrieve the user id of the session.

```
const applySchema = mongoose.Schema({
   title: { type:String, required:true },
   user: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "User"
   }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Apply', applySchema);
```

I created a controller for the management of a user's applies

```
exports.getAllApplies = (req, res, next) => {

  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  const userId = res.locals.currentUser.id

  Apply.find({ user:userId })
     .then(applies => res.status(200).json({ message:'success', 
         applies:applies }))
     .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error:error, message: 'Failed'}))
}
```

Function allowing to consult an apply

```
exports.getOneApply = (req, res, next) => {
   res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
   const userId = res.locals.currentUser.id

   Apply.findOne({ _id:req.params.id, user:userId })
      .then(apply => res.status(200).json({ message: `Apply with id 
            ${apply._id} success`, apply:apply}))
      .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error:error, message:'Failed'}))
 }
```

The routes of my api, I add an auth middleware to allow requests only for a user with a token

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const applyCtrl = require('../controllers/apply');


router.get('/', auth, applyCtrl.getAllApplies);
router.get('/:id', auth, applyCtrl.getOneApply);

module.exports = router;
```

I apologize for the length of the post, if you have any questions, I would be happy to answer them.

Thank you in advance for your help and your answers.

Comment: MongoDB supports the associations as relational databases do. The syntax is different but concepts are all the same.

Comment: Yes after research, I tried to achieve this, I updated the post.

Comment: What is now the issue?